# Issues with SIMD functions in GNU c & c++

Tags: c++, c

**Environment Details:**

Machine: Core i5 M540 processor running Centos 64 bits in a virtual machine in VMware player.
GCC: 4.8.2 built from source tar.

**Issue:**
I am trying to learn more about SIMD functions in C/C++ and for that I created the following helloworld program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pmmintrin.h>

int main(void){
    __m128i a, b, c;
    a = _mm_set_epi32(1, 1, 1, 1);
    b = _mm_set_epi32(2, 3, 4, 5);
    c = _mm_add_epi32(a,b);
    std::cout << "Value of first int: " << c[0];
}
```

When I look at the assembly output for it using the following command I do not see the SIMD instructions.

```
g++ -S -I/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2 -msse3 -O3 hello.cpp
```

Sample of the assembly generated:

```
movl    $.LC2, %esi
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
movabsq $21474836486, %rsi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIxEERSoT_
xorl    %eax, %eax
```

Please advise the correct way of writing or compiling the SIMD code.

Thanks you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your compiler is optimizing away the calls to `_mm_foo_epi32`, since all the values are known. Try taking all the relevant inputs from the user and see what happens.

Alternately, compile with `-O0` instead of `-O3` and see what happens.

Comment: I need some more help. I created following small program and it does not give me the correct output.

    #include <iostream>
    #include <pmmintrin.h>
    #include <emmintrin.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main(void){
     __m128i a;
     int aa[4] __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = {1,2,3,4};
     a = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)aa);
     cout << "Value of first int: " << a[0];

    }

the output that I get is not the right one, instead of getting 1 I am getting 8589934593.

Comment: This would be better stated as a separate question; the comment system is not designed or intended to take large pieces of code.